# Giving a script permission to execute mkdir on its own

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, permissions

I have a file I downloaded from the Internet. When I run it in the osx terminal, one of the automated things it does is make a new directory in my /usr/local/bin, but this fails as terminal says that permission is denied. How do I give this file permission to execute the mkdir command? I know how to give myself permission with sudo, but not how to give this file permission to do the same on its own.

Comment: what user is it running as? presumably you `mkdir /usr/local/bin/deleteMe` without `sudo`ing - the script should typically be running as your user, so it too should be able to write to that directory.

Comment: So I noticed that I myself do not have permission to mkdir in /usr/local/bin without using sudo, which is probably why the file can't do it either. How do I give myself this permission? I don't have to become the superuser do I? I feel like that's overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give your user permission to that folder by running `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/bin/`. Once you make sure you own the directory and sub-directories (`ls -l /usr/local` and `ls -l /usr/local/bin`) your script should be able to write to those directories as well.

As a general rule of thumb, `sudo`ing to work around permission errors just makes the problem worse. Fixing the underlying permissions take a few extra minutes but is better in the long run.

Comment: Thanks, that did it.